# How to build play framework sample application using sbt (not play)?

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

I am getting an NPE when invoking sbt within  a sample app.

Please note: we can not run our overall app using "play": we need to be able to run this via sbt.

```
C:\apps\playframework\samples\scala\websocket-chat>sbt
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sbt.StringUtilities$.nonEmpty(StringUtilities.scala:14)
        at sbt.impl.GroupArtifactID.$percent(DependencyBuilders.scala:50)
        at $f01bf36bc7174607fa7f$.$sbtdef(C:\apps\playframework\samples\scala\websocket-chat\project\plugins.sbt:8)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at sbt.compiler.Eval$.getValue(Eval.scala:420)
        at sbt.compiler.Eval$$anonfun$4.apply(Eval.scala:87)
        at sbt.compiler.Eval$$anonfun$4.apply(Eval.scala:87)
        at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$evaluateSetting$1.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:150)
        at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$evaluateSetting$1.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:148)
        at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$flatten$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:115)
        at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$flatten$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:115)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
        at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$flatten$1.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:115)
        at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$flatten$1.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:115)
        at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$evaluateSbtFile$1.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:110)
        at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$evaluateSbtFile$1.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:110)
        at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$loadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:507)
        at sbt.Load$$anonfun$sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1$1.apply(Load.scala:502)
        at sbt.Load$$anonfun$sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1$1.apply(Load.scala:501)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:501)
        at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadSettings$1$2.apply(Load.scala:500)
        at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadSettings$1$2.apply(Load.scala:500)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
        at sbt.Load$.loadSettings$1(Load.scala:500)
        at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$expand$1(Load.scala:523)
        at sbt.Load$.loadSettings(Load.scala:528)
        at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$loadSbtFiles$1(Load.scala:464)
        at sbt.Load$.defaultLoad$1(Load.scala:475)
```

**EDIT** Here is the project\plugins.sbt

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe" % "sbt-mima-plugin" % "0.1.5")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-scalariform" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "0.6.0")

addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % Option(System.getProperty("play.version")).getOrElse("2.0"))

libraryDependencies <+= sbtVersion { sv =>
  "org.scala-sbt" % "scripted-plugin" % sv
}
```

The line:

```
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % Option(System.getProperty("play.version")).getOrElse("2.0"))
```

causes the following:

```
[warn]
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: play#sbt-plugin;2.0: not found
        at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:214)
```

**EDIT** More details

```
C:\apps\play\framework>sbt package
"sbt13"
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
[info] Loading project definition from C:\apps\play\framework\project
[warn]  module not found: play#sbt-plugin;2.2.3
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/2.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/2.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\S80035683\.ivy2\local\play\sbt-plugin\scala_2.9.2\sbt_0.12\2.2.3\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/play/sbt-plugin_2.9.2_0.12/2.2.3/sbt-plugin-2.2.3.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: play#sbt-plugin;2.2.3: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]          play:sbt-plugin:2.2.3 (sbtVersion=0.12, scalaVersion=2.9.2)
[warn]
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: play#sbt-plugin;2.2.3: not found
        at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:214)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit the `project/plugins.sbt` and change

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % System.getProperty("play.version"))
```

to

```
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % Option(System.getProperty("play.version")).getOrElse("2.2.3"))
```

You can also get an updated Play version, where this issue seems to be fixed.

You can also set the system property `play.version`, if you want.

#### Edit

Make sure you are including Typesafe repository in the resolvers in your `plugins.sbt`.

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
```

Comment: Hi, what does the play.version have to do with this? In any case i will try what you say - but would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: It's just that the `sbt-plugin` is bound to the play version (for different play versions there will be different sbt plugins). Normally the version is set as a system property, but for the play version you're using seems to be a bug.

Comment: The plugins.sbt does not have the specific entry you mentioned. I have copied it to the OP for your perusal (and showing that I added the line you suggested).  That extra line has errors (also included in the OP)

Comment: You should have had the entry. However I have made a mistake, suggested by the way it was done in the original [plugins.sbt](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.0.x/samples/scala/websocket-chat/project/plugins.sbt) for that example. The version should be actually "2.0.1" or whatever play version you're using. I've updated my answer. Btw. which version of Play are you using?

Comment: 2.2.X . where do I see precise version?  Clearly i do not use play at all. This was/is first foray.

Comment: You should have the line in the [build.sbt](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.3/samples/scala/websocket-chat/project/plugins.sbt) then, however you still are missing the part `.getOrElse("2.2.3")`, which you may just add.

Comment: yes i did add the .getOrElse, and am recompiling: unresolved dependency: play#sbt-plugin;2.2.3: not found

Comment: Could you put complete report (especially which repos were tried) and the output  of `show externalResolvers` to the OP? And seems you're also missing this line from `plugins.sbt`: `resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"`

Comment: op updated.  and I am adding the line to plugins.sbt now

Comment: You don't need to add this line, but seems you're not using play 2.2.x, for that particular version of Scala and sbt you can only use play up to `2.1.5` (which is the value you should have set).

Comment: OK I am going to give this a rest now (and myself too!) I will award now for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on lpiepiora's answer, but up-to-date (as his suggested fix did not work for me). I run the latest versions of everything (as of April 4, 2016) and got the scala play samples to build and run using the below:

Edit the project/plugins.sbt and make sure you have this line:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.3")
```

Explicitly specifying play version as 2.2.3 will work just fine, as this is what the samples are targeting.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer.